# Outlook won't autocomplete "TO" when typing a contact's last name

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

I have Outlook 2010 on a Windows 7 laptop. When I go to send an email, if I start typing a contact's last name in the "TO" line, Outlook will not auto-populate a list of names that fit the description of what I have typed so far. However, if I start typing the first name instead, the auto-fill feature will work properly based on what I have typed so far.

The company I work for has 20k+ employees. If I want to email someone like "Michael Hutch", typing the first name "Michael" gives me a list of around 800 names to choose from. However, if I type "Hutch" the auto-complete won't list any names.

My old laptop with Outlook 2003 was able to auto-complete by last names. Is there a way to enable this in Outlook 2010?

Comment: You could go through your contacts and change each name from, say, "Michael Hutch" to "Hutch, Michael". Would that be feasible?

Comment: Related question at answers.microsoft.com: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/auto-complete-wont-search-by-last-name/82c9e64e-80ff-4213-8d49-a499dca3c635. It looks like there's nothing to do, and some Microsoft employees/MVPs are explaining that everything works as expected. Yay for a great user experience!

Comment: What happens if you type "Hutch" followed by Ctrl+K (or alternatively in the Message tab, Names group, click the button Check Names.)? Do you have more than one Address book?

Answer (score 6):

http://theservermonkey.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/understanding-how-autocomplete-works-in-outlook-2010/

When searching for a recipient based on text you type in the “To”, “CC”, or “BCC” fields, auto-complete looks at the following fields:

> 1. Display Name (i.e. Jane K. Doe)
> 2. Primary SMTP E-mail address (i.e. Jane_Doe@domain.com)
> 3. Exchange Alias (i.e. janedoe)
> 4. legacyExchangeDN attribute in Active Directory (more on this later)

Auto-complete does NOT search against any of the following criteria:

> First Name (if it is different from the display name, for example if the display name contained a nickname instead of the legal first name, which is listed in the recipients’ “first name” field in Active Directory)
>
> Last Name (unless one of the above four fields starts with the last name)
>
> Username (unless one of the above four fields starts with the username, or is set to match the username)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It explains the fields that autocomplete uses to suggest email addresses, but it doesn't help the OP figure out if there's a way to get it to sort by last name, or explain why it's not possible. For example, can a person control the display name or Exchange Alias, or if they are sending to people in a GAL is this set by the Exchange admin?

Answer (score 3):

To search by last-name, you must change the order in which Display Name is
constructed from the first and last names.

To do that in Outlook 2010 :

- Go into File > Info > Account Settings > Account Settings
- In the Address Books tab, click the address book in question,
  and then the Change button
- In the dialog box, check "File As (Smith, John)"
- Click the Close button

[image]

I remark that Autocomplete shows addresses of people you’ve sent messages to
previously.
Autoresolution/Autoresolve is the one that looks in your Contacts folder or
other address book.
You may populate the Autocomplete list by an entire address book by sending
a message to all the contacts (doing that in Offline mode will let you
delete it before it is really sent), although I don't know if this will work
for a 20K+ list.

To do Autoresolve, type "Hutch" followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,
or alternatively in the Message tab, Names group, click the button Check Names.

Comment: Will this work for a global address book? My company has a shared list of employee emails.

Comment: By default the GAL is searched first. I don't have experience with making this work for the GAL - you will have to experiment and see. At worst you could try the "GAL to Autocomplete list" trick I described above.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the *Account Settings* method does not work for the Global Address List.

Comment: You might need help from the administrator of the GAL.

Answer (score 0):

Type the last name and then click the "Check Names" button:

[image: Check Names Button]

This will bring up a window that lists all contacts with that last name.